# Why do I need to use std::move in the initialization list of a move-constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference, move-semantics, move-constructor

Let's say I have a (trivial) class, which is move-constructible and move-assignable but not copy-constructable or copy-assignable:

```
class movable
{
  public:
    explicit movable(int) {}
    movable(movable&&) {}
    movable& operator=(movable&&) { return *this; }
    movable(const movable&) = delete;
    movable& operator=(const movable&) = delete;
};
```

This works fine:

```
movable m1(movable(17));
```

This, of course, does not work, because `m1` is not an rvalue:

```
movable m2(m1);
```

But, I can wrap `m1` in `std::move`, which casts it to an rvalue-reference, to make it work:

```
movable m2(std::move(m1));
```

So far, so good. Now, let's say I have a (equally trivial) container class, which holds a single value:

```
template <typename T>
class container
{
  public:
    explicit container(T&& value) : value_(value) {}
  private:
    T value_;
};
```

This, however, does not work:

```
container<movable> c(movable(17));
```

The compiler (I've tried clang 4.0 and g++ 4.7.2) complains that I'm trying to use `movable`'s deleted copy-constructor in `container`'s initialization list. Again, wrapping `value` in `std::move` makes it work:

```
    explicit container(T&& value) : value_(std::move(value)) {}
```

But why is `std::move` needed in this case? Isn't `value` already of type `movable&&`? How is `value_(value)` different from `movable m1(movable(42))`?

Comment: A standards reference will hopefully follow, but not all uses of a && variable should be destructive - you could imagine a actor that takes a dozen steps with its && argument before trashing it.  So when you construct another object with a && variable, you still need to say that this particular use is allowed to be a move...

Comment: A named value of type `T&&` is an lvalue, whereas an unnamed value of the same type is an rvalue.

Comment: On my phone so not going to answer, but a named temporary is an lvalue. Here, `value` is an lvalue expression.

Comment: @Yakk: No standards reference needed.  That's a suitable answer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That's because `value` is a named variable, and thus an lvalue. The `std::move` is required to cast it back into an rvalue, so that it will cause move-constructor overload of `T` to match.

To say it another way: An rvalue reference can *bind* to an rvalue, but it is not itself an rvalue. It's just a reference, and in an expression it is an lvalue. The only way to create from it an expression that is an rvalue is by casting.

Answer (score 5):

> How is `value_(value)` different from `movable m1(movable(42))`?

A named rvalue reference is an lvalue (and will thus bind to the deleted copy ctor), while a temporary is, well, an rvalue (a prvalue to be specific).

`§5 [expr] p6`

> [...] In general, the effect of this rule is that named rvalue references are treated as lvalues and unnamed rvalue references to objects are treated as xvalues [...]

Aswell as from the example:

```
A&& ar = static_cast<A&&>(a);
```

> The expression `ar` is an lvalue.

The above quotes are from non-normative notes, but are an adequate explanation, since the rest of clause 5 goes and explains which expressions *only* create xvalues<sup>†</sup> (aka, only the specified expressions and none else will create xvalues). See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11581903/500104) for an exhaustive list.

† xvalues are one subgroup of rvalues, with prvalues being the other subgroup. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3601602/500104) for an explanation.