# Rvalue to lvalue conversion and "named-refs-are-lvalues" rule

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference

There're lots of rvalue related quiestion but I didn't found answers to these exact questions.

I can't wrap my mind around "named reference is a lvalue reference" rule of thumb.

It seems really strange -- we declare the reference as an **rvalue** but since we have to somehow use this reference (otherwise, what's the point?), we name it and since it's named it's an **lvalue** after all!

Consider this code:

```
int&& foo(int&& arg)
{
    arg = 10;
    return arg; // ERROR, `arg` is an lvalue since it's named!
}
foo(1);
```

The questions are:

1. When exactly does arg become an lvalue?
2. What would be the type of arg if the function was void and b) and c) lines were not present?
3. Lot's of articles (just citing first found [result](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/12/15/understanding-lvalues-and-rvalues-in-c-and-c)) say that there may be implicit lvalue to rvalue conversion but the opposite direction is not possible -- why? This example shows that `arg` -s converted from `int&&` to `int&` and then tries to implicitly convert `int&` to `int&&` which causes compilation error -- just the opposite behaviour! That's why we need `std::move` which is basicaly an explicit static_cast to rvalue type.

Comment: *"named reference is a lvalue reference"*, the value category is a property of expressions, not variables/references/etc

Comment: For function arguments, think of what it can "bind to" more than how it is used inside; once _inside_ the function, almost anything is an rvalue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`arg` the variable has type `int&&` and no value category.

`arg` the expression  (it is an expression at lines 3 and 4) has type `int` and value category "lvalue"

Lvalue to rvalue conversion changes the value category of an expression, without changing its type. If you write `arg+1` inside the function, the lvalue expression `arg` of type `int` would undergo this conversion to produce a prvalue expression of type `int`, since that's what built-in `+` requires.

There are no "lvalue to rvalue" or reverse conversions between int& and int&& because expressions never have reference types. The error in your program is a failure to **bind** an rvalue reference (of type int&&) to an lvalue expression (of type `int`).

Answer (score 3):

We should refine the *"if it has a name it's an lvalue"* rule, to the more exact form:

> **If it has a name, then when used as an expression it is an lvalue.**

But don't we always use a variable as an expression?

Usually yes, but not necessarily. See the following function:

```
void foo(A&& a) {
    // decltype of the variable a - is rvalue
    static_assert(std::is_rvalue_reference_v<decltype(a)>);

    // decltype of the expression a - is lvalue
    static_assert(std::is_lvalue_reference_v<decltype((a))>);
}
```

Note that `a` doesn't just *become* an lvalue. If it is being used as an expression - which is a common use for a variable - then the expression is an lvalue reference.

In the code above, the `decltype` of `a` is `A&&` thus still an rvalue reference.

On the other hand, `(a)` turns the use of `a` into an expression in that context, thus the `decltype` of `(a)` is `A&` - an lvalue reference.

You can think about that as: the expression that uses the variable `a`, can be considered as an lvalue reference to `A&&` (i.e. `A&& &`), which with reference collapsing becomes `A&`.

---

The fact that the variable `a` is still an rvalue, and only the expression `a` is an lvalue, is not so commonly in use. Usually we just deal with `a` as an expression. However, it is being used when we want to forward an `auto&&` parameter, e.g.:

```
[](auto&& v){ foo(std::forward<decltype(v)>(v)); } (A{});
```

---

[From C++ Reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category): An expression, can be categorized into one of three options:

- if it **has an identity** and **cannot be moved from**, it is called an **lvalue expression**
- if it **has an identity** and **can be moved from**, it is called an **xvalue expression**
- if it **doesn't have an identity** and **can be moved from**, it is called a **prvalue ("pure rvalue") expression**

Expressions that can be moved from are called "rvalue expressions". Both prvalues and xvalues are rvalue expressions. Since C++17, prvalues are no longer moved from, due to mandatory copy elision.

Expressions that have an identity are called "glvalue expressions" (glvalue stands for "generalized lvalue"). Both lvalues and xvalues are glvalue expressions.

Having an identity is considered as being possible to determine whether the expression refers to the same entity as another expression, such as by comparing addresses of the objects or the functions they identify.

---

In the following code we compare *lvalue*, *prvalue* and *xvalue* expressions:

```
void foo(A&& a) {
    // below we send the expression a to bar, as lvalue
    bar(a);

    // std::move(a) is an xvalue expression
    bar(std::move(a));

    // A{} is a prvalue expression
    bar(A{});
}
```

There is a list of expressions that may create a an *xvalue* (see the link below, for "What expressions create xvalues?"), but the most common two expressions for that are `std::move` and `std::forward`.

Creating a *prvalue* is easy, you just create an object without a name, or use an object in an expression that requires a prvalue (there is a conversion from lvalue to prvalue).

---

Code to play with: https://godbolt.org/z/so746KcqG

---

See also:

- [What expressions create xvalues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11581903/what-expressions-create-xvalues)
- [What are rvalues, lvalues, xvalues, glvalues, and prvalues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601602/what-are-rvalues-lvalues-xvalues-glvalues-and-prvalues)
- [On how to recognize Rvalue or Lvalue reference and if-it-has-a-name rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27554296/on-how-to-recognize-rvalue-or-lvalue-reference-and-if-it-has-a-name-rule)
- [Rvalue Reference is Treated as an Lvalue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28483250/rvalue-reference-is-treated-as-an-lvalue)
- [Why is a named rvalue reference an lvalue expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56316766/why-is-a-named-rvalue-reference-an-lvalue-expression)

Answer (score 0):

Question 3 asks why an implicit conversion from an lvalue (whether a reference or not) to an rvalue reference is not allowed. This could be based on the constraint that [rvalue references](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Rvalue_references) can bind only to rvalues. This constraint is essential, for example, to overload functions in order to implement copy and move constructors.

About whether an expression can have a reference type, this [blog post](http://scottmeyers.blogspot.com/2015/02/expressions-can-have-reference-type.html) by Scott Meyers is very useful. The [quote](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.type) from the latest standard draft:

> If an expression initially has the type “reference to T” ([dcl.ref],
> [dcl.init.ref]), the type is adjusted to T prior to any further
> analysis. The expression designates the object or function denoted by
> the reference, and the expression is an lvalue or an xvalue, depending
> on the expression.

Thus, to be very accurate, an expression can have reference type but this reference-ness is removed for all practical purposes.