# Why is a named rvalue reference an lvalue expression?

Tags: c++, rvalue-reference, value-categories

I know that a named reference is an lvalue:

```
int x = 1;
int& ref1 = x;
int&& ref2 = std::move(x);
```

I've read the explanation — that is because we can take the address of those `ref1` and `ref2`.

But when we take the address of a reference we actually take the address of the referenced object, don't we? So this explanation doesn't seem to be correct.

So why a named reference is an lvalue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per [[expr.prim.id.unqual]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.prim.id.unqual) (8.1.4.1 Unqualified names):

> [...] The expression is an lvalue if the entity is a function,
>   variable, or data member and a prvalue otherwise; it is a bit-field if
>   the identifier designates a bit-field ([dcl.struct.bind]).

Per [[basic]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic#6):

> A *variable* is introduced by the declaration of a reference other
>   than a non-static data member or of an object. The variable's name, if
>   any, denotes the reference or object.

The declaration

```
int&& ref2 = std::move(x);
```

is a "declaration of a reference other than a non-static data member." Therefore, the entity denoted by `ref2` is a variable. So the expression `ref2` is an lvalue.

Comment: By this article, [link](https://blog.knatten.org/2018/03/09/lvalues-rvalues-glvalues-prvalues-xvalues-help/). what is the rhs? what is lhs - ref2?

Comment: @Bulat What is "rhs"? What is "lhs"?

Comment: rhs - right hand side, lhs - left hand side of the expression.
So rhs - std::move(x), lhs is int&& ref2 or ref2.

Comment: @Bulat Thank you for answering your own question. :)

Comment: `lhs` - you said is `lvalue`. This [article](https://blog.knatten.org/2018/03/09/lvalues-rvalues-glvalues-prvalues-xvalues-help/) introduce this terms: `lvalues`, `rvalues`, `glvalues`, `prvalues`, `xvalues`. So what is `rhs` and `lhs` in this terms?

[More info about rhs, lhs](https://books.google.ru/books?id=To3xpkvkPvMC&pg=PA255&dq=named+reference+is+an+lvalue&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjSxYbazLviAhWcwcQBHTn8AyoQ6AEIQTAD#v=onepage&q=named%20reference%20is%20an%20lvalue&f=false)

Comment: @Bulat `std::move(x)` is an xvalue (thus also an rvalue).

Comment: @Bulat BTW, of course I know that "rhs" means "right hand side." What I meant to ask was actually "What is the right hand side? What is the left hand side?" Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Thanks! So static data member is a variable, while non-static data member is not a variable? What's the point?

Comment: @beginpluses Well, I'm not sure. Maybe you can ask a new question.

Answer (score 3):

That explanation is just a simplification. lvalues aren't defined by being "something you can take the address of", but by a specific set of rules about the value category of expressions. Those rules are carefully constructed so as to result in a self-consistent language in which everything fits together reasonably neatly.

That being said, the explanation *does* rather fit here, if you consider that by writing `ref1`, you're not really naming "the reference" but the thing being referred to. That's the magic of references: you're supposed to consider them name aliases rather than entities in their own right.

There are some abstraction leaks surrounding this (particularly, member references), but that's the gist.

You ought to forget about notions like "the reference is an lvalue" and instead think about *expressions*. Objects have types; expressions have value categories.

Comment: So every variable and every function is just defined to be an lvalue by the standard?

Answer (score -1):

Here is an explanation from Scott Meyers's book "Effective Modern C++":

> In fact, `T&&` has two different meanings. One is rvalue reference, of course. Such references behave exactly the way you expect: they bind only to rvalues, and their primary *raison d’être* is to identify objects that may be moved from.
>
> ```
> void f(Widget&& param); // rvalue reference
>
> Widget&& var1 = Widget(); // rvalue reference
>
> auto&& var2 = var1; // not rvalue reference
>
> template<typename T>
> void f(std::vector<T>&& param); // rvalue reference
>
> template<typename T>
> void f(T&& param); // not rvalue reference
> ```
>
> The other meaning for `T&&` is either rvalue reference or lvalue reference. Such references look like rvalue references in the source code (i.e., `T&&`), but they can behave as if they were lvalue references (i.e., `T&`). Their dual nature permits them to bind to rvalues (like rvalue references) as well as lvalues (like lvalue references). Furthermore, they can bind to `const` or non-`const` objects, to `volatile` or non-`volatile` objects, even to objects that are both `const` and `volatile`. They can bind to virtually anything. Such unprecedentedly flexible references deserve a name of their own. I call them universal references.

Comment: The question asks why an expression consisting of an unqualified-id denoting a variable of an rvalue reference is an lvalue. Universal references are irrelevant here. The expression `param` is an lvalue regardless of whether `T` is deduced as a lvalue reference type or not. Sorry for downvote.