# Not able to override an && operator in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, compiler-errors, operator-overloading

I am learning designing principles course and as I was trying to implement a open close principle on my own where we define different specification which is then sent to filter class to check whether the given entity is valid entity or not.

These are my virtual class

```
template <typename T>
struct Specification {
    virtual ~Specification() {}
    virtual bool is_satisfied(T* item) = 0;
};


template <typename T>
struct Filter {
    virtual std::vector<T*> filter(std::vector<T*> items, Specification<T>& spec) = 0;
    
};
```

```
template <typename T>
struct AndSpecification : Specification<T> {
    Specification<T>& first;
    Specification<T>& second;
    AndSpecification(Specification<T>&& first, Specification<T>&& second) : first(first), second(second) {}
    
    bool is_satisfied(T* item) override {
        return first.is_satisfied(item) && second.is_satisfied(item);
    }

};


struct BetterFilter : Filter<Product> {
    std::vector<Product* > filter(std::vector<Product*> items, Specification<Product>& spec);
};

struct ColorSpecification : Specification<Product> {
    Color color;
    ColorSpecification(Color color) :color(color) {}
    bool is_satisfied(Product* item);
};

struct SizeSpecification : Specification<Product> {
    Size size;
    SizeSpecification(Size size) :size(size) {}
    bool is_satisfied(Product* item);
};
```

These are my inherited classes

And based on these classes I am trying to override && operator which is defined in global scope.
`

```
template <typename T>
AndSpecification<T> operator&&(Specification<T>&& one, Specification<T>&& two) {
    return AndSpecification<T>{one, two};
}
```

When I am trying to compile this I am getting error

`Error   C2440   '<function-style-cast>': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'AndSpecification<Product>'  DesignPrinciples    C:\Users\ania\source\repos\DesignPrinciples\Main.cpp    24`

I tried different methods to define like

```
AndSpecification<Product> operator&&(Specification<Product>&& one, Specification<Product>&& two) {
    return AndSpecification<Product>(one, two);
}
```

but even then it failed. Can someone explain me what am i doing wrong here. How can I rectify it ?

**Edit1:**
Thanks to @Yksisarvinen I am able to compile when I add std::move in template method

```
AndSpecification<T> operator&&(Specification<T>&& one, Specification<T>&& two) {
    return AndSpecification<T>{std::move(one), std::move(two)};
}
```

But when i run it, it fails with read access violation

I am getting this exception at this line

`AndSpecification<Product> spec = ColorSpecification(Color::green) && SizeSpecification(Size::large);`

**Edit 2:** [Here](https://onecompiler.com/cpp/3ymgw92a4) is the minimal reproducible example.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/fd7avnj5v)

Comment: `one` and `two` are lvalues, because they have names. You still need `std::move` on them to make them rvalues.

Comment: The arguments to your `&&` override are r-values. You can only call them with r-values. Change them to `const &`

Comment: Kinda related, searching for a better duplicate: [Why is a named rvalue reference an lvalue expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56316766/why-is-a-named-rvalue-reference-an-lvalue-expression)

Comment: Well, that means you have Undefined Behaviour somewhere in your code. Might be related to your move operations, but you need to debug that yourself.

Comment: Lots of references to temporaries; I think we need a [mcve] to check everything.

Comment: in general don't overload that operator, as it can't work in the same way as the built-in one - use a named function

Comment: I am sharing the complete codebase which i have written. Let me know if anything else is required  ```https://onecompiler.com/cpp/3ymgw92a4```

Comment: @NeilButterworth: I assume you specifically mean the shortcut evaluation? That can be implemented. In this case, `AndCondition` indeed does not call `second.is_satisfied` if the first filter returns `false`. What it can't do is shortcut evaluation when the operator _itself_ is called. It will always combine the two filter expressions `one` and `two`.

Comment: @MSalters yes i did mean that and stylistically i have never seen an overload of && or || that made much sense, and this is no exception

Answer (score 0):

C++ is not garbage-collected. If you're using pointers, you need to keep track of ownership. If you're storing references, you need to make sure that the reference refers to an object that is still alive.

`AndCondition` fails in this regard. It stores two references, but has no way to know if the objects referenced are still alive.

`std::unique_ptr<>` could be a workable solution. A `std::unique_ptr` keeps the unique (sole) ownership of an object, and supports derived classes.

A `std::unique_ptr` can be moved - this is by design. This transfers ownership. Thus, `AndSpecification(std::unique_ptr<Specification<T>>&& first, std::unique_ptr<Specification<T>>&& second)` makes perfect sense. This *takes* ownership.