# Move assignment operator not invoked

Tags: c++, move-semantics

Can somebody explain this code:

```
void Move(Person& lhs, Person&& rhs)
{
    lhs = rhs; //invokes copy assignment instead of move assignment
    //lhs = (Person&&) rhs; //casting to && invokes move assignment.
}
```

Comment: Anything with a name is automatically lvalue, and this includes `rhs`.

Comment: `rhs` is an `lvalue`. See dupe: [why named rvalue ref is an lvalue expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56316766/why-is-a-named-rvalue-reference-an-lvalue-expression)

Comment: ... so to get what you want, you have to do: `lhs = std::move (rhs);` (which is what `std::move` is for).